# How do I solve the following problem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose that $f:[0,\to \infty) \to \mathbf{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)\ge \sqrt{x}$ for all $x\ge 0$. Show that for each $r>0$ there exist $c>0$ such that $f(c)=r$.

Comment: Let $r>0$. If there is no $c>0$ such that $f(c)=r$, then show that $f(x)<r$ for all $x$ (use IVT). So this contradicts the assumtion.

Answer (score 1):

$r^2 > 0$ so $f(r^2) > \sqrt{r^2} = r > 0 = f(0)$.

So intermediate value theorem states there for any $y; f(0) < y < f(r^2)$ there is a $c_y; 0 < c_y < r^2$ so that $f(c_y) = y$.  Let $y = r$ and we are done.